# How to concatenate {variable} to href tag in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to use variable in curly braces in anchor tag's href string.
suppose value of {entry.email} is abc@xyz.com then I am trying to do this`<a href="mailto:"+{entry.email}>{entry.email}</a>` to generate anchor tag
`<a href="mailto:abc@xyz">abc@xyz`

in following code

```
const rows = props.contacts.map((entry, index) => {
    return (
        <tr key={index}>
            <td><a href="mailto:"+{entry.email}>{entry.email}</a></td>
        </tr>
    );
```

But clearly this is not working or even compiling. How do I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
href={`mailto: ${entry.email}`} // or {`mailto: ${entry.email || ""}`} to avoid null or undefined being stringified
```

or

```
href={"mailto: "+ entry.email} // or {"mailto: " + (entry.email || "")} to avoid null or undefined being stringified
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```js
<a href={`mailto:${entry.email}`}>
```

Comment: How does this differ to the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation whether using quote marks or string literals will work as long as they are declared inside curly braces...

OPTION ONE:

```
<a href={"mailto: "+ entry.email}>
```

OPTION TWO:

```
<a href={`mailto: ${entry.email}`}>
```